# Why is my child div not showing inside its wrapper div?

Tags: html, css

I've run into an issue that doesn't make much sense to me.

I have a wrapper `div` and two children `div` within it.

One `div` is set to a static `height` of `height: 600px`, and the other `div` has a `height` set to dynamically take up the `height` of its parent container, i.e. it has `height: 100%`.

However the div with the dynamic `height` isn't showing up at all.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;      
}
.div2 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 60%;
    height: 600px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {      
    background-color: green;
}
```

I would like for `div1` to dynamically take up the height of the parent `div` where the height is essentially set by `div2`.

Unfortunately, I can't use CSS Flexbox as I need to support older IE browsers with this project.

Here is a JSFiddle for easy access: https://jsfiddle.net/y8gdbzd6/22/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you give the fixed height `height: 600px` to the parent div and then apply `height: 100%` to the child elements like below

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use CSS Flexbox as I need to support older IE browsers with this project. I would love to use Flexbox as it's such a sleek solution.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to settle with this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your parent element (`.wrapper`) has no height set, its default height is `auto`. To make `.div1` fill the parent container, you have to set the height of the parent first because your `.div1` tells the browser to give it a height 100% of the height of its parent.
Example: If you set the height of your parent to `600px` and set the height of the `.div1` to `50%`, it would be `300px` or half of the height of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%` is not taking because its parent `div` has no `height`. So please give some specific height to its parent div. Now I have given `height:100vh` to  `.wrapper` class.

```css
body{margin:0}
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;  
  vertical-align:top;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the idea is that I'm trying to have the height of the `wrapper` div equal to the height of `div2` at all times. I was hoping `height: auto` for the `wrapper` div would work but it seems that's not the case.

Comment: But if parent div has `height:auto` then child div can't identify height in percentage. For this you have to give any specific height to its parent div.